# Is it possible to display python input statements in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I've python code that takes user input, hence I'm using lots of input statements. Now I'm creating GUI using Tkinter and want to display those input statements in Tkinter. Is there a way to to it?

For ex.

```
var=float(input("enter a number"))
```

Now I want to show the input statement "enter a number in Tkinter". Is it possible to do it? If yes, how?

Comment: `input` reads its value from the console, but tkinter provides a gui. This makes the console redundant for user input. You should use a TextBox widget or similar.

Comment: Unless you expect to run from the terminal and use the statements to build the GUI itself, then it might make sense. Anyway, this is too broad - checkout `tkinter` `Label` widget, it has a `var` argument.

Comment: Do you mean a console-like behaviour of your tkinter application? If so, you can redirect inputs/outputs to/from `stdin`/`stdout` streams.

Comment: CommonSense- Yes, I'm somewhat referring to console like behavior. I know how to redirect/send print statements to GUI text box: sys.stdout = PrintOutput(). But how to redirect input statements from code to GUI?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the `input` function, you could user tkinter's `askstring` command. This will bring up a small dialog box with the question asked and return the user's entry to the script.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.simpledialog as sd

def getUserInput():
    userInput = sd.askstring('User Input','Enter your name')
    print(f'You said {userInput}')

root = tk.Tk()
btn = tk.Button(root,text="Get Input", command=getUserInput)
btn.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

If you wish to ask for numerical values, tkinter also has `askfloat` and `askinteger` functions. These allow you to specify minimum and maximum values.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.simpledialog as sd

def getUserInput():
    userInput = sd.askstring('User Input','Enter your name')
    print(f'You said {userInput}')

def getUserFloatInput():
    options = {'minvalue':3.0,'maxvalue':4.0}
    userInput = sd.askfloat('User Input','Enter an approximation of Pi',**options)
    print(f'You said pi is {userInput}')

def getUserIntegerInput():
    options = {'minvalue':4,'maxvalue':120}
    userInput = sd.askinteger('User Input','How old are you?',**options)
    print(f'You said you are {userInput}')

root = tk.Tk()
btn1 = tk.Button(root,text="Get String Input", command=getUserInput)
btn1.grid()
btn2 = tk.Button(root,text="Get Float Input", command=getUserFloatInput)
btn2.grid()
btn3 = tk.Button(root,text="Get Integer Input", command=getUserIntegerInput)
btn3.grid()
root.mainloop()
```